# How do I handle answers that suggest downloading content?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, answers

I'm new to review tasks and want to make sure I'm doing this right.

How do I handle answers where the poster suggests the fix requires downloading third party content from dropbox or other places. I encountered it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683180/using-solver-in-vba-sets-calculation-mode-to-manual/36701998#36701998) and was wondering what the best practice is?

Comment: Non-official download link, user with 0 reputation... Very sketchy even if it is real.

Comment: That's what I figured. Just wasn't sure. It would be nice to have a discussion as well I think to have an answer for this in a general sense. What if it is someone with a decent amount of rep for example?

Comment: To their credit, the name matches the LinkedIn profile of someone who works as support for Solver (company name: Frontline Systems). I've commented on the answer asking about the links.

Comment: @Jeff If it's worth adding any more skepticism, the user is also unregistered.

Comment: Related to the post more than the problem, I had been contacted by the rep earlier and was surprised he posted to SO. I am trying to deal with this offline so an answer can be posted.

Comment: @OldUgly good to know, that you trusted the user/answer. It would be great if we could update it so future visitors can trust it as well, without having to chat up support beforehand ;)

Comment: "The downloads do NOT address the problem. Please do NOT download them." is what OldUgly commented on that post 8 hours ago.

Comment: Could you re-post this question in a more general form in Meta? I'd like to know the community norms for downloadable/external content in both questions and answers. (E.g., Is such content acceptable? Should it be flagged? Should it be discouraged? What alternatives are there that we can recommend?) I'd ask it myself, but I don't want to steal any potential upvotes from you given that I'd be half-copying your question :P

Comment: No need to repost, just edit this question to be more generic still.